# Bind FITS image to tkinter canvas in Python

Tags: python, astronomy

**See main point below code chunk for quick summary**

For research, I'm trying to write a photometry program in python (I know there is software out there, but there's a specific reason I'm writing my own). I am using Anaconda with Python 3.6 and can get the FITS file image to render, but I want to be able to click on a point and perform photometry.

Basically I want to bind the image to a tkinter canvas and have a click event to return the location.

I've been looking at almost the exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501192/how-to-display-picture-and-get-mouse-click-coordinate-on-it), but the key differences are that I'm using a FITS file and python 3.6 (which changes a lot of the features in that example)

My code thus far (using much of what that example showed) is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
import scipy as sp
import tkinter as tk
import PIL

hdulist = fits.open('00000039.sat_26624U.fit')
hdulist.info()
scidata = hdulist[0].data

histo = sp.histogram(scidata, 60, None, True) 
display_min = histo[1][0]
display_max = histo[1][1]
pic = plt.imshow(scidata, cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=display_min, vmax=display_max, origin="lower")

#Try tk stuff
root = tk.Tk()

#setting up a tkinter canvas
frame = tk.Frame(root, bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, bd=0)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)

#Add image
hold = tk.PhotoImage(pic)
canvas.create_image(0,0,image=hold,anchor="nw")

#function to be called when mouse is clicked
def printcoords(event):
    #outputting x and y coords to console
    print (event.x,event.y)
#mouseclick event
canvas.bind("<Button 1>",printcoords)

root.mainloop()

hdulist.close()
```

Which shows the image but gives me an error at:

```
#Add image
hold = tk.PhotoImage(pic)
canvas.create_image(0,0,image=hold,anchor="nw")
```

That says:

TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type AxesImage)

**Main Point:

I can't get a FITS image to bind to a tkinter canvas. I don't know how to click that image and get the location of the mouse click. I want to be able to click a few points, get their locations, and use those locations to draw a few annuli.**

I have plenty of other issues, but that's my main hang up right now. Eventually I will be trying to track them (move to the next picture and search roughly the same area until I find the object again, placing the annulus) and counting the pixels inside, but I can cross that bridge later (unless anyone has ideas now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to some people, I found the issue to be that a tkinter canvas needs a file type like .gif or .png to bind an image to the canvas. So I changed

```
pic = plt.imshow(scidata, cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=display_min, vmax=display_max, origin="lower")
```

to

```
plt.imsave("tempimgfile.gif", scidata, cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=display_min, vmax=display_max, origin="lower")
```

and

```
hold = tk.PhotoImage(pic)
```

to

```
hold = tk.PhotoImage(file="tempimgfile.gif")
```

saving my numpy array as a gif file just long enough to bind, then deleting it after.

Bottom line: **Convert a FITS file to .gif or other compatible type**

It may not be the most elegant fix, but it worked

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some changes in the code. First of all I would prefer to use the **Place()** method in **Tkinter** . You can look at place Method here [how to i position buttons in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574168/how-to-i-position-buttons-in-tkinter/41575504#41575504)

Second thing : By using the place method it will be suitable for your application.

Hint: **Place()** Method works with **x and y co-ordinates**. So the two elements can overlap in Tkinter using **Place()** but it is not possible in Grid.

Now with Place() method place the image in some area in Tkinter window let say the image size is 100x100 and then make a button with the function call and place it behind the image giving the same co-ordinates in Place() Method. So when a user will click on image it will actually calls the function behind the button.